# Create Table plugin dynamically using javascript API's

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to create Table plugin dynamically using javascript api's in jquery mobile.

Now i'm creating table plugin using append method in javascript, but i want create this in javascript api's.

Html

```
 <table data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-responsive table ui-shadow" id="today_app">
        <tr><th>Name</th><th>Duration</th></tr>
      </table>
```

javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < serviceName.length; i++) {
$('#today_app').append('<tr><td>'+serviceName[i].name+'</td><td>'+serviceName[i].from+'</td></tr>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code without jquery mobile append...

```
var   = document.getElementById('today_app');
for (var i = 0; i < serviceName.length; i++) {
    var row       = document.createElement("tr");  
    // create table cells
    var td1       = document.createElement("td");
    var td2       = document.createElement("td");
    td1.innerHTML = serviceName[i].name;
    td2.innerHTML = serviceName[i].form;
    // adding cells to row
    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);
    tableObj.appendChild(row);
}
```

Comment: Fine with your answer. But how to create table in javascript api's from table itself. like <table data-role="table">...</table>

Comment: In your code, creating element from from td. JQM has table plugin like, <table data-role="table"><tr><td>...</td></tr></table>.  Suppose table contains 50 td means, we have write createElement for 50 times. thats why im creating from javascript api's.. Refer this. http://www.tricedesigns.com/portfolio/docs/javascript.html#list. this is from Bootstrap JS Api's. I want like this in JQM